# jQuery toggle() does not work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, animation

TL;DR Version at the bottom!

I'm working on a project for my final in a college course, but it also happens to be a useful tool that is designed to be used from mobile devices (smartphones, specifically) at work that I'd like to make usable for coworkers.

But I've run into a problem that I have not been able to solve, after literally hours of research. This is not an exaggeration; I've tried every resource I could think of and/or find. Dozens of Google searches using different terminology, asking other [experienced] programmers, fiddling around with the code, reading documentation, reading numerous questions and answers here on SO, and probably a few other things. I must just not be asking the right query of Google, because this seems like something that would be super-common.

The problem is just as the question title states: the `.toggle()` function in jQuery isn't firing upon the `touchstart` event on iOS devices. It is specific to the OS and not the browser, as it does not work in Safari or Chrome on iOS. It does, however, work in everything else I've tried it on (including Chrome(Win), Firefox(Win), and Chrome(Android)).

**The Scenario:**

I've created a small div-button with the three-line or "hamburger" menu glyph on it. When tapped, a menu listing navigation options is supposed to slide in from the right side of the screen, and slide back out when the button is tapped again.

I'm using `jQuery 2.1.1`, `jQueryUI 1.11.2`, as well as a custom file for scripts simply called `thd_scripts.js`.

Here's the script code in the header of the document:

```
<script src="includes/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/scripts/thd_scripts.js"></script>
```

The only line of code in `thd_scripts.js`:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#menuButton').on( 'touchstart', function(e){
        alert('Event fired!');
       $('#menuWrapper').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 400);
    })
})
```

And the code for the button in the HTML:

```
<div id="menuButton">
    <img id="menuSprite" class="menuButtonImage" src="images/menu_button.svg" />
</div>
```

I know that the 'touchstart' event is properly triggering on iPhones because the alert fires. But the toggle never does.

The following is a list of code variations I've tried (that I can remember at the moment):

```
.bind() / .on()
click / touch / tap / touchstart (only touchstart seems to fire on iOS)
.toggle() [no parameters]
.toggle('slide')
.slideToggle()
```

**TL;DR Version**

I cannot get a menu to slide in from off-screen on iOS/iPhone devices at the touch of an on-screen div. `touchstart` event is firing as it should, jQuery animation as `.toggle('slide')` is not working.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I just want to double-check here - you're targetting `#menuWrapper` with your javascript, yet I can't see `#menuWrapper` in your HTML. You are targeting the correct element, yes?

Comment: @Christian Varga - Excellent point and question, and that is correct - I AM targeting the correct element. #menuWrapper holds the #menu element for the purpose of ensuring the box-shadow on #menu is displayed properly during the animation.

Edit: I would assume that if I weren't targeting the proper element, that the whole thing would fail in more than just iOS, yes? I'm honestly asking, as I'm new enough to this to not assume I know what I'm talking about... in any of it. ;)